# Integrar notificación IPN de Mercado Pago en Laravel

Tags: laravel, mercadopago

Estoy intentando integrar las notificaciones IPN de Mercado Pago en Laravel, la ruta es esta:

```
Route::post('/notifications', 'MercadoPagoController@notifications');
```

El método notifications en MercadoPagoController lo hago super simple para probar que devuelva correctamente la respuesta, es este:

```
  public function notifications(Request $request){
    return http_response_code(200);
  }
```

Hago pruebas con la página que ofrece Mercado Pago para definir la notification_url:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/panel/notifications/ipn

https://www.yoursite.com/notifications?topic=payment&id=123456789

Pero recibo un error 419 respuesta desconocida, que podrá estar mal?

Comment: Creo que lo expuesto justo aqui: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris te lo resolvería y aparte te explica el problema

Comment: Muchas gracias BetaM, solucionado.

Comment: Responde tu mismo si gustas tu pregunta

Comment: Bien, agregada la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado, el problema era que no estaba prestando atención al token CSRF, y para solucionarlo debía excluir la ruta de la protección CSRF ya que Mercado Pago no sabe qué token CSRF enviar.

Entonces, esto se hace agregando la URL a la propiedad $except del middleware VerifyCsrfToken.

Agrego el ejemplo de la documentación con el detalle de como se escribe la url de notifications de Mercado Pago:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'https://example.com/notifications*',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```